# connect QTreeWidgetItem to database

Tags: c++, database, qt, user-interface

Im working on a project where im trying to build a QTreeWidget that has multiple QTreeWidgetItems
and once i click on a particular item it connects to a database and shows a query result in a tableview model, until now every thing works fine.

the problem is that i want each item to output different resut depending on some criteria on the same table where this criteria is only changing the value of an attribute, and this value is the same of the item name. for example item named 122 and the table has atribute called no. when we click on item 122 the result of this query must be shown (select * from table where no=122)

any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have a QTableView backed by a `QSqlQueryModel` or `QSqlTableModel`.

You can connect to the signal `QTreeWidget::itemSelectionChanged()` and then in the slot you get the current item with `selectedItems()[0]`. Then you create your query:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("select * from table where no=:no");
query.bindValue(":no", number);
query.exec();
```

Finally you can use `setQuery (const QSqlQuery & query)` on the model. This should update your view.

I hope I understood correctly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you very much ar31 for your help :D                           By the way can i use in the signal itemClicked instead of itemSelectionChanged.